# How to sandbox clojure.string/blank? with Clojail in Clojure?

Tags: java, clojure, lisp, sandbox, clojurescript

I use **Clojail** for sandboxing and it works great for `clojure.core` functions but when it comes to other namespaces it does not work as expected.

I need to sandbox(restrict) `clojure.string/blank?` function.

```
(defn blacklist-symbols
  []
  (testers/blacklist-symbols
    '#{alter-var-root
       intern
       eval
       clojure.string/blank?
       ...}))
```

This should throw a **Security Exception** but it does not.

```
(sb '(do
      (println "Hey: " (clojure.string/blank? ""))))
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean in this context? Do you get an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: @nhouser9 updated question.

Answer (score 0):

it should look like this, if I understand correctly,

```
(defn blacklist-symbols
  []
  (testers/blacklist-symbols
    #{'alter-var-root
      'intern
      'eval
      'clojure.string/blank?
       ...}))
```

a fully tested example

```
user=> (ns my.project
  #_=>   (:use [clojail.core :only [sandbox]]
  #_=>         [clojail.testers :only [blacklist-symbols blacklist-objects]]))
nil
my.project=> 

my.project=> (def tester [(blacklist-symbols #{'alter-var-root 'clojure.string/blank?})
        #_=>              (blacklist-objects [java.lang.Thread])]) ; Create a blacklist.
#'my.project/tester
my.project=> (def sb (sandbox tester :timeout 5000))
#'my.project/sb
my.project=> 

my.project=> (sb '(println (clojure.string/blank? "")))

AccessControlException access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "createClassLoader")  java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission (AccessControlContext.java:457)
```

You can find the example in library home page
https://github.com/Raynes/clojail

Comment: '#{alter-var-root
       intern
       eval
       clojure.string/blank?
       ...} and  #{'alter-var-root
      'intern
      'eval
      'clojure.string/blank?
       ...} are same things.You can put apostrophe before the collection declaration.

Comment: It does not work.Still get the same result.How did you come up with this result?

Comment: you are getting this exception because you did not add ~/.java.policy file to your Classpath.This is not the Security Exception that Clojail throws.This is configuration exception.